# Extracting Wikipedia entries from text

Tags: python, regex, wikipedia, named-entity-recognition

I have a large text, and I want to parse this text and identify (e.g. wikipedia entries that exist within this text).

I thought of using regular expression, something like:

```
pattern='New York|Barak Obama|Russian Federation|Olympic Games'
re.findall(pattern,text)
```

... etc, but this would be millions of characters long, and re doesn't accept that...

The other way I thought about was to tokenize my text and search wikipedia entries for each token, but this doesn't look very efficient, especially if my text is too big...

Any ideas how to do this in Python?

Comment: Define "wikipedia entries" .. do you mean text for which there exists a wikipedia article?  Then the problem can have multiple solutions, and is dynamic in time!

Comment: yes, I mean article names basically

Comment: in your example you gave `Olympic Games` there is a wikipedia article about `Games` and about `Olympic` what would you have the code do in this case? return 3 entries? or just 1? the question is, you will be searching through every combination of substrings of different lengths for articles, this is very messy.. what could your end result possibly be?

Comment: Ideally I'd be looking for the longest string, but I would implement it in a way to give the user the ability to choose to display all matches or just the longest match. The point behind this system is to have a system that can effeciently recognize the occurances of the entries of a large list of substrings within some text.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be getting all Wikipedia articles and pages and use then the Sentence tagger from NLTK.
Put the created sentences, sentence by sentence into an Lucene Index, so that each sentence represent an own "document" in the Lucene Index.

Than you can look up for example all sentences with "Barak Obama", to find patterns in the sentences.

The access to Lucene is pretty fast, I myself use a Lucene Index, containing over 42000000 sentences from Wikipedia.

To get on the clan wikipedia txt file, you can download wikipedia as xml file from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

and then use the WikipediaExtractor from the Università di Pisa.
http://medialab.di.unipi.it/wiki/Wikipedia_Extractor

Answer (score 0):

I would use [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) to [tokenize](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize-module.html) the text and look for valid wikipedia entries in the token. If you don't want to store the whole text in-memory you can work line by line or sizes of text chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this with Python? `grep --fixed-strings` is a good fit for what you want to do, and should do it fairly efficiently: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#index-g_t_0040command_007bgrep_007d-programs-175

If you want to do it in pure Python, you'll probably have a tough time getting faster than:

```
for name in articles:
    if name in text:
        print 'found name'
```

The algorithm used by `fgrep` is called the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) but a pure Python implementation is likely to be slow.

Comment: yes, the whole system is in python, it would be inconvenient to use something else, but thanks for pointing that out..

Comment: You could call `grep` from Python if it's running on a UNIX system, although if you're on windows it would be harder.

Answer (score 0):

The Gensim library has a threaded iterator for the ~13GB wikipedia dump.  So if you're after specific terms (n-grams) then you can write a custom regex and process [each article of text](http://textminingonline.com/training-word2vec-model-on-english-wikipedia-by-gensim).  It may take a day of cpu power to do the search.

You may need to adjust the library if you're after the uri source.